# Faking a request with same data gives two different responses

Tags: c#, http

I am trying to emulate functionality with a website. I have analysed the two requests using Firefox's LiveHeader add-on and also Wire Shark. One of the requests is an OPTIONS request and the other is a POST request with a file. My post request method works flawlessly as tested elsewhere.

I am sending the same data according to Wire Shark but I'm receiving a Connection Close, instead of a keep alive in both requests which I suspect is causing the failure. According to wireshark, I'm sending the same data so why might I be receiving a connection-close instead of a keep-alive response?

Comment: It does - I've had to implement http protocol version 1.0 to enable it

Comment: Well it'd be a lot easier and require a lot less guessing if you'd just show both full request-response pairs.

Comment: What data should I export from Wireshark?

Comment: The request-line and request-headers of the HTTP data.